# Crystal Report: Showing Single Column Data into Rows of Multiple Columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

**Crystal Reports** in **Visual Studio 2008** with **C#**
Normally Data from single column comes like

**Column1**
val1
val2
val3
val4
val5
val6
val7
val8

**BUT,I want to show data from my Single column in following format:**

**Column1**
val1        val2        val3        val4
val5        val6        val7        val8
val9        val9        val10        val11
.......

.......

.......

Please help me out to get above output in Crystal Report

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by splitting the details section in to columns.

- Right click the Details section in
  Design view and select Section
  Expert.
- Check the box `Format with
  Multiple Columns` An extra tab on the
  top right will appear called layout.
- In the Layout tab set the Width to
    4.5cm (for Portrait) and ensure that `Across then Down` is selected.

This will split the details in to columns of 4.5 cm wide.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

right mouse button the `Detail`s section.  select `Section Expert...`, in Common tabs, there's a `Format with Multiple Columns`

Comment: Format with multiple Columns have been checked before... still the format which i shown above is not coming. can you have any other options?

Comment: on width size input, did you make it smaller? and also make the printing directions: across then down

Comment: you're welcome, just thinking why i didn't get any upvote considering i also provided the complete answer(albeit the last step is in comment).  anyway, you're welcome nonetheless ;)