# SSRS: Show Single Column Data in Multiple Columns

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, business-intelligence

I have an issue that is similar to this one here:
[Crystal Report: Showing Single Column Data into Rows of Multiple Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644263/crystal-report-showing-single-column-data-into-rows-of-multiple-columns)

However, I couldn't apply the solution to SSRS in Business Intelligence Developer Studio (BIDS). 
Is there a SSRS equivalent to Crystal Report's "Format with Multiple Columns"?

My dataset result looks like this:

**Column1**

val1

val2

val3

val4

val5

val6

val7

val8

I want the report to look like this:

**Column1     Column2**

    val1                val5 

    val2                val6

    val3                val7

    val4                val8

Comment: What do you mean by 'Business Intelligence' in this case? Crystal Reports is arguably a Business Intelligence tool.

Comment: What I mean is SQL Sever Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008

Comment: OK I have suggested an edit to the question which is under peer review.